# Using Javascript to randomly select 10 exercises from exercise bank (JSON)

Tags: javascript, json

The "exercises" in the title refers to questions, but StackOverflow does not allow the word "question" in the title.

I'll start out by saying that I am very much a newbie when it comes to Javascript. What I'm attempting to do is build a question bank using JSON, formatted like this:

```
 {"questionlist":[
  {
  "question":"Test question 1",
  "option1":"Answer1A",
  "option2":"Answer1B",
  "option3":"Answer1C"
  },
  {
  "question":"Test question 2",
  "option1":"Answer2A",
  "option2":"Answer2B",
  "option3":"Answer2C"
  },
  {
  "question":"Test question 3",
  "option1":"Answer3A",
  "option2":"Answer3B",
  "option3":"Answer3C"
  }
]
}
```

And so on. What I would then want to do is create a page that, using Javascript, randomly selects 10 questions from the question bank mentioned previously (let's say the question bank will contain about 100 questions in total) and displays these 10 questions in much the same way a real-life quiz would do (i.e. not one at a time, but rather all of them). Then just have radio buttons to select the correct answer and finally have a "submit" button that checks the answers.

It's ridiculously hard to Google this stuff - I've mostly come across quizzes ABOUT javascript and JSON or designs where the order of the answers is randomised (not the questions themselves). Again, sorry for not being able to get overly technical with my vocabulary here. I hope someone can help, even with a rudimentary design - it's going to be for personal use of about 3 people, so it does not have to be perfectly optimised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### So, let's have a TLDR of your aim.

You have an array of 100 questions. You would like to have an other array of 10 questions selected from the first array so as in the resulting array there're no repeating questions.

### How would we do it?

You should pick a random index within the array bounds 10 times, and each time check if you haven't picked that index already (avoid duplicates, in other words).

### The realisation.

I suppose that you have this object stored in some variable. If you have got the input as string which is a valid JSON, you could use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

```
var obj = {"questionlist":[..., ..., ...]}
```

First of all, we get the array of all the questions by the `questionList` key.

```
var list = obj.questionlist;
```

Now let's create the array to contain the resulting 10 questions.

```
var resultList;
```

We are going to populate it by pushing 10 times a random index that would be `>=0` and `<list.length`, and not forgetting to make sure it's a unique index every time we push.

First let's decide how we pick a random index.

The random float within [0,1] can be received by executing `Math.random()`. Now to get the number within `0 ... list.length` we just multiply it by the `list.length`. Not forgetting it could be a float, so making it an integer by throwing away the part after the floating point (i.e., floor the number).
The resulting formula is `~~(Math.random()*list.length)`,

Let's write all the code now.

```
for( var k = 0; k < 10; k++ ) {
    var randIndex = ~~(Math.random()*list.length);
    //check if the index is not duplicate
    if( resultList.indexOf(randIndex) < 0)
        resultList.push(randIndex);
    else
        // else the index is duplicate so we don't need it and should move one step back in the loop
        k--;
}
```

Now the `resultList` contains 10 random non-repeating question indexes. You could now output the resulting list of 10 random questions by looping the `resultList` array.

```
for( var k = 0; k < resultList.length; k++ )
    console.log(list[resultList[k]]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort the array randomly and take a slice of n items from it would also do the trick:

```
yourArrayOfItems.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5).slice(0, 10);
//                    ^ random sort method       ^ take 10 items
```

Comment: Wow, that's really a curious thing, +1 for teaching me an interesting way!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, where 'n' is the number of random elements you want,

```js
const items = {
    "questionlist": [{
            "question": "Test question 1",
            "option1": "Answer1A",
            "option2": "Answer1B",
            "option3": "Answer1C"
        },
        {
            "question": "Test question 2",
            "option1": "Answer2A",
            "option2": "Answer2B",
            "option3": "Answer2C"
        },
        {
            "question": "Test question 3",
            "option1": "Answer3A",
            "option2": "Answer3B",
            "option3": "Answer3C"
        },
        {
            "question": "Test question 4",
            "option1": "Answer3A",
            "option2": "Answer3B",
            "option3": "Answer3C"
        },
        {
            "question": "Test question 5",
            "option1": "Answer3A",
            "option2": "Answer3B",
            "option3": "Answer3C"
        },
        {
            "question": "Test question 6",
            "option1": "Answer3A",
            "option2": "Answer3B",
            "option3": "Answer3C"
        },
        {
            "question": "Test question 7",
            "option1": "Answer3A",
            "option2": "Answer3B",
            "option3": "Answer3C"
        },
        {
            "question": "Test question 8",
            "option1": "Answer3A",
            "option2": "Answer3B",
            "option3": "Answer3C"
        }
    ]
}

function random_item(questions, n) {
    var arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr.push(questions[Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length)])
    }
    return arr

}

console.log(random_item(items.questionlist, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

This function selects N questions out of an array by random:

```js
var bank = {
  "questionlist": [{
      "question": "Test question 1",
      "option1": "Answer1A",
      "option2": "Answer1B",
      "option3": "Answer1C"
    },
    {
      "question": "Test question 2",
      "option1": "Answer2A",
      "option2": "Answer2B",
      "option3": "Answer2C"
    },
    {
      "question": "Test question 3",
      "option1": "Answer3A",
      "option2": "Answer3B",
      "option3": "Answer3C"
    }
  ]
}

function selectN(bank, n) {
  var list = bank.questionlist;
  if (list.length < n) n = list.length; //to prevent endless loop
  var set = new Set(); //using a set to prevent duplication
  while (set.size < n) set.add(list[Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)]);
  return Array.from(set)
}

console.log(selectN(bank, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

`Math.random()` is a function, which gives a floating point number between 0 and 1.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

`Math.floor()` takes a floating point number, and rounds it down to the next full integer.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor

```js
var list = {"questionlist":[
  {
  "question":"Test question 1",
  "option1":"Answer1A",
  "option2":"Answer1B",
  "option3":"Answer1C"
  },
  {
  "question":"Test question 2",
  "option1":"Answer2A",
  "option2":"Answer2B",
  "option3":"Answer2C"
  },
  {
  "question":"Test question 3",
  "option1":"Answer3A",
  "option2":"Answer3B",
  "option3":"Answer3C"
  }
]
}

list = list.questionlist

console.log(
    list[Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)]['question']
);
```